# Writing out sheet to text file using POI event model

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using [XLSX2CSV](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java) example to parse large sheets from a workbook. Since I only need to output the data for specific sheets I added an if statement in the process method to test for the specific sheets. When the condition is met I continue with the process.

```
   public void process()
            throws IOException, OpenXML4JException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

        ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings = new ReadOnlySharedStringsTable(this.xlsxPackage);
        XSSFReader xssfReader = new XSSFReader(this.xlsxPackage);
        StylesTable styles = xssfReader.getStylesTable();
        XSSFReader.SheetIterator iter = (XSSFReader.SheetIterator) xssfReader.getSheetsData();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            InputStream stream = iter.next();
            String sheetName = iter.getSheetName();

            if (sheetName.equals("SHEET1")||sheetName.equals("SHEET2")||sheetName.equals("SHEET3")||sheetName.equals("SHEET4")||sheetName.equals("SHEET5")){           

            processSheet(styles, strings, stream);

            try {

                System.setOut(new PrintStream(
                        new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\edennis.AD\\Desktop\\test\\"+sheetName+".txt")));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }


           stream.close();


            }
         }
    }
```

But I need to output text file and not sure how to do it. I tried to use the System.set() method to output everything from system.out to text but that's not working I just get blank files.

Comment: Why not simply set the print stream you want as the `output` object in `MyXSSFSheetHandler` ? Quite possibly via controlling what PrintStream you pass into the main `XLSX2CSV` class when you create it say?

Comment: I resolved it by just passing it a new prinstream in the MyXSDFSheetHandler like you said, thanks. If you want you can answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer:

In [XLSX2CSV](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java) there's one key line near the end, inside demo `main` method:

```
XLSX2CSV xlsx2csv = new XLSX2CSV(p, System.out, minColumns);
```

When creating the new `XLSX2CSV` object, we pass in a a PrintStream object, that gets used to output the text to. As explained in the constructor:

```
/**
 * Creates a new XLSX -> CSV converter
 *
 * @param pkg        The XLSX package to process
 * @param output     The PrintStream to output the CSV to
 * @param minColumns The minimum number of columns to output, or -1 for no minimum
 */
public XLSX2CSV(OPCPackage pkg, PrintStream output, int minColumns) {
```

So, if you pass in a File based PrintStream rather than System.out, you'll get the CSV written to that file instead